# Internet Explorer ignore my css

Tags: css, browser-compatibility

I am creating my personal blog, but Internet explorer are **** me. About 5 hours I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong, well what is my problem ?

Well, I created breadcrumb for my website, only for specific custom types - reviews. All browsers are ok with this, but internet explorer (I have IE 10) are pushing my sidebar away.

If you open for example this my review http://milanchymcak.com/reviews/fix-redirect-virus-review - if you open it in firefox or chrome, its ok. But in Internet explorer my sidebar is gone. I don't know what to do.

So I was looking for answer on google and everybody is telling that this will fix that

```
<!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 10]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" /><![endif]-->
```

But this doesnt work at all. Internet Explorer ignores this too. I will be very happy for any help.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a WordPress question but a general HTML / CSS question, as such you will likely get better answers elsewhere (StackOverflow).

If you add this to your `meta` tags inside the `head` tag:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />`

This will render the page like IE7.

**However I don't recommend this**; if you are developing a theme really you should focus on using newer HTML5 doc types / coding practices and fixing the problems there.

You might find Microsoft's http://modern.ie website helpful in identifying and tracking other issues.